# Angular2 Router error: cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomePage'

Tags: angular, router

I just started using the new routing library (@angular/router v3.0.0-alpha.7) but following the official [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) leads to error below:

```
browser_adapter.ts:74: EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomePage'
```

**Question is - how do I get rid of the error and make the router behave as expected? Have I missed a setting?**

(Same error appears when using the alpha.6 version.)

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <p>Angular 2 is running...</p>
        <!-- Routed views go here -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    `,
    providers: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

*app.routes.ts*

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePage } from './pages/home/home';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: '', component: HomePage }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

*home.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: '<h1>Home Page</h1>'
})
export class HomePage {
}
```

*main.ts*

```
/* Avoid: 'error TS2304: Cannot find name <type>' during compilation */
///<reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />

import { bootstrap } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I was having same error due to missing template of `'<router-outlet></router-outlet>'`
This may be due to typo error too in `'<router-outlet></router-outlet>'`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You have an error in your `app.component.ts` 
Looks like you declared a directive in the providers array.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <p>Angular 2 is running...</p>
        <!-- Routed views go here -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `,
     directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] //here
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: My error got resolved as I added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` .

Not getting error even when I don't have  `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` in @Component section.

Comment: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES  is no more relevant for angular 2. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 86):

Although @JS_astronauts already provided a solution, I think it would be instructive to explain the error...

The primary outlet is set when Angular parses an HTML template and finds [directive RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterOutlet-directive.html), i.e., when it finds RouterOutlet's selector: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.

Although your template does contain `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, your component does not contain `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]`, so Angular won't look for any of the directives defined by that constant:

```
export const ROUTER_DIRECTIVES = [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkWithHref, 
 RouterLinkActive];
```

So when Angular parses AppComponent's HTML templates, if it doesn't recognize `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` so it just ignores it.  Later, when Angular tries to render the default route component (HomePage), it complains because doesn't know where to put it.

---

This error can also happen if you have a typo in your element selector, e.g.:

```
<roter-outlet></roter-outlet>
```

In this case, even if your `directives` array is set correctly, Angular will never find the required `<router-outlet>` element.

Comment: Just a note for anyone using later versions: 'directives' property of @Component has been removed in RC6.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658186/angular-2-component-directive-not-working

Comment: Re typo in your element selector: Or if your template is simply missing the tag all together...

Comment: Another Note: if you're copy and pasting, it should say `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` . It's missing the `u` in beginning and end tags

Comment: Shame that the correction from roter to router doesn't minimum character change requirements

Answer (score 7):

It should be `directives metadata` instead of `providers`,

```
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing this error randomly and only when I publish on the live server. I have never experienced this when working locally. When I say randomly, sometimes it works fine, when I refresh for example, it throws that error mentioned above and just showing symbols on the screen.
I am working on Angular 2.

Any guidance / help will be much appreciated.