# Angular 2 component directive not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am a beginner in angular 2 and I want to make my first app working. I am using TypeScript.
I have the **app.component.ts** in which I have made a directive to another compoent called **todos.component** but I am getting the following error at compile time:

```
[0] app/app.component.ts(7,3): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ moduleId: string; selector: string; directives: typeof TodosComponent[]; templateUrl: string; s ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
[0]   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

My code is like this:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {TodosComponent} from './todos/todos.component';

@Component({
  moduleId : module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  directives: [TodosComponent],
  templateUrl : 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls : ['app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title: string = "Does it work?";
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1> Angular 2 application</h1>
{{title}}
<app-todos></app-todos>
```

**todos.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId : module.id,
  selector: 'app-todos',
  template: '<h2>Todo List</h2>'
})

export class TodosComponent {
    title: string = "You have to do the following today:";    
}
```

Without the directive, the app works fine. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't you creating a directive in wrong way? from the Angular2 Documentation `import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[myHighlight]' })
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
       renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', 'yellow');
    }
}
`

Comment: If you are using the latest Angular final, `directives` doesn't exist in `@Component` metadata anymore (hence the error). If you are going off a tutorial, you should try to find a newer one. There have been a lot of changes in a short period of time, and a lot of tutorials are outdated. I would personally just go to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/) and start from there.

Comment: Agree to @peeskillet, take a look at this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html. Just don't use `directives:` of @Component, only add it into `app.module.ts`'s `declarations:`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In your `app.component.ts` you define `directive: [TodosComponent]`.
The directive property has been removed in RC6 from the `@Component()` decorator.

The solution to this, is to:

1. create an NgModule and
2. declare the TodosComponent inside the `declarations: []` array.

See here for an example of AppModule:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html

Comment: @Alexander What if I want to load a directive for a specific component unlike to the whole application?
FYI - I was trying to load the tinymce text editor.

Comment: You should make a module out of that single component and declare both component and directive there.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski I found that 'angular lazy loading' easily does that. Same as in concept as you mentioned. Thanks
https://blog.nrwl.io/enable-lazy-loading-in-angular-2-apps-8298916056#.rxow48w0e

Answer (score 3):

module.id was added in intially when angular2 was at beta version.Since with new version and angular cli support it is not required to add **moduleId:module.id**,you can remove from .ts files