# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AchivementComponent'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm developing an Angular2 app and, I am stuck in routing configuration. I fallowed official documentation of Routing and Navigation and used them appropriately. It has fallowing routing structure.

```
-Login Page
-Home Page
   |-Achievement 
   |-Task
```

I have used auth guard to protect the home page routes. In the home page there are a header and links to navigate through child components. Currently if I click on a link, It loads the whole home page with child component,
also gives this error 
`EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AchievementComponent'` 
I checked everything and it looks correct, but I can't figure out any reason for this.

app-routing.module.ts

```
..
@NgModule({
    imports:[
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'login',    component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'home',     component: HomeComponent, canActivate [LoggedInGuard], 
                children:[
                    { path: 'achievement', component:AchievementComponent },
                    { path: 'task', component:TaskComponent },
                    { path: '', redirectTo:'achievement', pathMatch:'full' }
                ]
            },
            { path: '',         redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:'full' },
        ])
    ],
    exports:[
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig,firebaseAuthConfig),
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        AchievementComponent,
        TaskComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        UserService, 
        DataService, 
        LoggedInGuard, 
        StorageService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html file contails only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag.

home.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="validUser">
    .......
    <nav>
        <a routerLink="achivement" >Achivement</a>
        <a routerLink="task" >Task</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

[screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKJ6P.png)

can anyone give a solution

Comment: More explanation about this error here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/38284135/6503379

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason for this error is `*ngIf` part in *home.component.html* file. At the beginning `validUser` variable is `false`, After validating the user `validUser` value is changed to `true`.

Because of this, at the beginning there is no router-outlet to load child components, after `validUser` value changed to `true` and if one of the link is clicked both of root component and child components are loaded once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the `path: '', redirectTo: 'achievment' ...` route at the first position within the child routes, otherwise after a match with route

```
 { path: 'achievement', component:AchievementComponent },
```

the router will in addition match

```
 { path: '', redirectTo:'achievement', pathMatch:'full' }
```

Adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to

```
 { path: 'achievement', component:AchievementComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

should also work.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: My mistake, I only added part of the code, Now it is updated. Reason for the error is `*ngIf` part in `home.component.ts`

Comment: Would you be so kind to share your added part of code with us? I am having the same problem right now and don't know how to fix this :/