# Error : Cannot find primary outlet to load

Tags: angular

So i tried about everything i found online and nothing worked yet.

So i followed the doc on angular about routing : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Here is my login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  template: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and my login.component.html

```
<p>Test login</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

error: Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'LoginComponent'
    at getOutlet

So i'm kind of lost here. I tried using: "template: (HTML HERE)" instead of templateUrl, same thing...

Thanks !

By the way, it's not duplicate since ROUTER_DIRECTIVES have been deprecated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Router error: cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomePage'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950413/angular2-router-error-cannot-find-primary-outlet-to-load-homepage)

Comment: post your app.module.ts, router module/file , create working plunkr if possible..
Probably the root component which is loaded does not contain router-outlet.

Comment: Also, the component decorator should be using `templateUrl` rather than `template` if you using a html file for the template

Comment: @ParthGhiya I'll post it when i'm back home.

Comment: @garth74 I tried both ways. With template url and a seperate file as well with template with the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`** needs to be placed inside of **`rootcomponent`** or **`appcomponent`**.

Here, not sure but looks like you want to load **`loginComponent`** through **`router`** if I'm not wrong.

***So place/add `router-outlet` in your root or app component.***
(**NOTE:** And ***remove*** from **`LoginComponent`** if it is not your **`root/app component`**)

Comment: I'll try it when i'm back home and i'll let you know ! thanks

Comment: Allright so it worked !! Just to be sure, the HTML that was in the app.component.html is supposed to be visible in every other component right?

Comment: Yes exactly. It acts as a kind of master page which is visible in every other component and router-outlet is the one which displays different views according to your defined routing.