# Angular 4 routing - EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular4-router

I am new to Angular4.

While I am trying to explore the routing in Angular4, I am getting the below error

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'

I checked the numbers of links to fix but none useful yet.

- [Angular2 Router error: cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomePage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950413/angular2-router-error-cannot-find-primary-outlet-to-load-homepage)
- [Error : Cannot find primary outlet to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687040/error-cannot-find-primary-outlet-to-load)

This is how app looks like.

index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
</body>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {RouterModule, Routes  } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from './component/customer/customer.component';
import {appRoutes} from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   CustomerComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{useHash:true})
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routes.ts

```
import {RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {CustomerComponent} from './component/customer/customer.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: AppComponent },
 { path: 'customer',      component: CustomerComponent },
 {
 path: 'heroes',
 component: AppComponent,
 data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
},
{ path: '',
redirectTo: '/heroes',
pathMatch: 'full'
},
{ path: '**', component: AppComponent }];
```

app.component.html

```
<h1> {{title}} </h1>
<a router-link="">Home</a>
<a router-link="customer">customer </a>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app works!';
```

}

**What configuration is lacking here to get routing in action??**

Comment: I think router-outlet should be in main component inside app-root

Comment: Also the usage of router-link should be something like [router-link]="['/link']" , note that i pass an array to router-link

Comment: show ur app component code . ?

Comment: @Muthukumar, added,please check

Answer (score 3):

plese use the routerlink configuration correctly as i given below. `<a [routerLink]="['/customer']">customer</a>` will generate the link /customer/

Comment: checked still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `<router-outlet> </router-outlet>` from index.html to app.component.html
2. Change all links in app.component.html from `<a router-link="customer">customer </a>` to `<a routerLink="/customer">customer </a>`